# Lie-infinity structure in Lagrangian Floer theory ?

Tags: mirror-symmetry, floer-homology, lie-algebras, sg.symplectic-geometry

Is there (besides the A-infinity structure) also a L-infinity structure in Lagrangian Floer theory (forming together a G-infinity structure) - like in Hochschild cohomology ?

Comment: Shouldn't you be looking (and indeed finding) such a structure in Hamiltonian Floer cohomology?